# Stylelint Configuration with SCSS: Remove empty lines between first nested selector

Tags: sass, lint, stylelint

I'm trying to configure my .stylelintrc.json to work where there is always an empty line between selectors except for the first nested selector.

**Example**

This is what I have after linting with --fix

```
.class {
                 
    .is-active {
        color: red;
    }

    .is-disabled {
        color: grey;
    }
}

.block__container {

    &--grid {
                                
        /* autoprefixer grid: no-autoplace */
        grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto;
    }

    &--full {

        div {
           ....
        }
    }

    &--wide {

       div {
         ...
       }
    }
}
```

This is what I want the end result to be

```
//This is what I want
.class {
    .is-active {
        color: red;
    }

    .is-disabled {
        color: grey;
    }
}

.block__container {
    &--grid {                     
        /* autoprefixer grid: no-autoplace */
        grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto;
    }

    &--full {
        div {
           ....
        }
    }

    &--wide {
       div {
         ...
       }
    }
}
```

This is my `.stylelintrc.json` file:

```js
{
  "extends": [ "@wordpress/stylelint-config/scss" ],
  "rules": {
    "string-quotes": "single",
    "scss/at-extend-no-missing-placeholder": true,
    "selector-class-pattern": null,
    "selector-id-pattern": null,
    "declaration-empty-line-before": "never",
    "rule-empty-line-before": [
      "always",
      {
        "except": [
          "after-single-line-comment",
          "first-nested"
        ],
        "ignore": [
          "after-comment",
          "first-nested"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "at-rule-empty-line-before": [
      "always",
      {
        "except": [
          "blockless-after-same-name-blockless",
          "blockless-after-blockless",
          "first-nested"
        ],
        "ignore": [
          "after-comment",
          "first-nested",
          "blockless-after-blockless"
        ],
        "ignoreAtRules": [
          "import"
        ]
      }
    ]
  } 
}
```

What rules, options, or plugins do I need to use/extend to get that result? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`except: ["first-nested"]`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/rule-empty-line-before/#first-nested) option on the built-in [`rule-empty-line-before`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/rule-empty-line-before/) rule to always have an empty line before rules except for the first nested rule.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "rule-empty-line-before": [
      "always",
      {
        "except": [
          "first-nested"
        ],
        "ignore": [
          "after-comment"
        ]
      }
    ]
  } 
}
```

(In your config, you're ignoring the first nested.)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that having it in the "ignore" was backfiring for me. I get it now. Appreciate your help.